# How to force deep sleep on android phone for testing

Tags: android

I'm trying to reproduce a bug in a third-party-developed app that seems to occur when my tablet is awakened from several hours of sleep.  My understanding is the "power" button only turns off the screen, but does not activate true sleep until some period of time has passed.  Is there a way to force deep sleep other than waiting a few hours?

Although my test device is a tablet, we are most interested in what happens on phones.

Answer (score 2):

You can use terminal:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle -h
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the device unplugged from the computer and USB Debugging turned off clicking the power button will force it to sleep.

If you have it plugged in, turning off USB Debugging and disabling Background Data will also force it into sleep mode once you push the power button.

Comment: of course what @Josh states is nonsense - this is what wakelock is for - if some app acquires it the device will not go asleep when power button is presses, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/wakelocks-detect-no-sleep-issues-in-android-applications

Comment: @MarianPazdzioch That does not mean it is nonsense just that it only works for a subset of usage scenarios. It does not mean you should downvote it, especially when not offering an alternative improved solution.